# Is this server jsonp response is a valid one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I am the client guy who sends the server guy a request. My final goal is to send the request in **jsonp**.

This is the server response I get when I send the request with `?accept=json` (and get an invalid session error because it is not jsonp)

```
{"errorCode":-15,"errorDescription":"SessionNotFoundException - Session not found","success":false,"payload":null}
```

I can read it and it is fine.

**However**, this is the server response for `?accept=jsonp`:

```
jQuery171024326910870149732_1351429007451({"action":"", "type":"", "callerId":""}, {"errorCode":0,"errorDescription":"OK","success":true,"payload":null});
```

it is in the form of these 2 objects which I don't know how to read: `{a},{b}`.

When I use jQuery ajax call 
the output of the server's data is only the `{a}` part:

`Object {action: "", type: "", callerId: ""}`

**My 2 questions are:**

1. Is a server response with 2 objects (`{a},{b}`) is valid or not? Does the server guy makes a mistake by sending that kind of object or it is valid?
2. How do I read the jsonp object? what is wrong with my ajax call that I can't seem to be reading it right?

This is the ajax call I use:

```
$.ajax({
            url:url,
            dataType:'jsonp',
            success:function(data){
                console.log("data is,"data")
                //if the call was success
                if (data.success) {

                    //if errors
                }   else {

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Since it's 2 objects you're getting back, try using 2 objects in your success handler. `success:function(data1, data2){`  Let me know if that works.

Comment: I get a console error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token s " which I guess means that it doesn't understand how to read "data2", Any solutions? Maybe a way to define data2?

Comment: It's 2 separate, valid JSON blocks, so I don't think that matters. Are you in control of the server side JSON response or no?

Comment: no control on the server side.

Comment: Is it possible to write me an example of a valid $.ajax jsonp request with error and success so I can see how it should look? I think I play with the parameters such as "data" "dataType" because I am not sure how to write them and to put it down will simplify it for me

Comment: Alon, in short, you have a situation that jQuery, to the best of my knowledge, actually cannot solve! Thus, I've proposed an alternative to jQuery. See the answer below for full explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to actually verify that the success callback cannot handle 2 arguments, I tried a simple test with a 2 arg function and 2 objects passed into it:

```
function test(a,b) {
    console.info(a);
}

test({"name":"test"},{"hello":"world"});
```

This succeeded, since I passed two separate objects, in JavaScript Object Notation, into a function that expects 2 arguments.

Next, I recreated an example response with a simple PHP script:

```
<?php echo $_REQUEST["callback"]?>({"test":"test"},{"hello":"world"});
```

So, next step, I went ahead and modified the success callback so that it takes 2 arguments:

```
$.ajax({
            url:'http://local.sandbox.com/jsonp2/test.php',
            dataType:'jsonp',
            success:function(data, data2){
                console.log("data is " + data2)
                //if the call was success
                if(data.success) {
                   alert("yes");
                    //if errors
                }   else {
                    alert(data2.hello);
                }
            }
        });
```

Now, here's where I ran into a problem, as per the [jQuery AJAX Success Handler docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
>
> Function, Array A function to be
>   called if the request succeeds. The function gets passed three
>   arguments:
>
> - The data returned from the server, formatted according to
>     the dataType parameter;
> - **a string describing the status;**
> - and the jqXHR
>     (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object.
>
> As of jQuery 1.5, the
>   success setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will
>   be called in turn. This is an Ajax Event.
>
> - *emphasis is mine*

The 2nd parameter of the success handler is *always* going to be the status of the response, so my output was "data is success" in the console, and the alert in the else block is undefined.

jQuery's jsonp implementation was most certainly designed to handle a single object in the callback, as it substitutes a custom value for the callback query parameter, which the server uses as "padding" or a wrapper for the response, usually in the form "jQuery1232432423432432". The success handler, as per the docs, takes 3 arguments, where the first is the object and the last 2 are supplied by jQuery. The padded function only takes 1 argument. Thus, jQuery cannot solve this problem.

However, there is a technique to still utilize the existing server side response, assuming you have no control over what the server generates.

---

### **The Solution:  Use Script Tag Remoting, Without jQuery:**

```
// this is a custom function to make jsonp requests to the server.
function jsonp(url, callback) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    script.setAttribute("src", url + "?callback="+callback + "&cachebuster="+new Date().getTime());
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

To call the function, use it in place of the $.ajax call, except pass in a named callback handler:

```
jsonp(url, "myCustomSuccessFunction");
```

Make sure you define a custom, named success callback function:

```
function myCustomSuccessFunction(data1, data2) {
    console.info(data1);  // contains first object
    console.info(data2);  // contains second object

    // do stuff w/said objects here

}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your reply. I am testing it to see if it works (so far it doesn't work but I guess this is something wrong that I am doing on my code)

Comment: In your test you do set the type to jsonp this might affect the signature of the handler since neither of the two are (readily) available when inserting a script tag instead of requesting. Jsonp calls do not actually request anything but simply inserts a tag and let the browser handle the rest

Comment: @RuneFS, I assume you're referring to dataType. If it's not jsonp, the cross domain request fails. If it is, it fails because the response from the server contains 2 objects, not 1, and the success handler expects 1 single JSON object, while the other 2 parameters are expected to receive meta data.

Comment: @Alon, the key is that you have to make sure you define "myCustomSuccessHandler". Also, there is a typo, I'll update to fix it. The jsonp command should look like this: `jsonp(url, "myCustomSuccessFunction");`. The callback must be in quotes.

Comment: when I execute the script I get in the console the error: 400 (Bad Request) for this link: http://muki.foo.bar.com/something//api/1234/delete?callback=DeleteSomethingAjaxCall&cachebuster=1351434600126. Does it fail for cross browsing issues? (since I send a request to muki.foo.bar from foo.bar)?

Comment: I can't resolve that link. It appears to point to nowhere. The point of jsonp is to make cross domain calls, so assuming everything is in place, this should work. Try the url in the browser to verify you're not missing something.